# python-3 parallelizing my functions issue

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am using python-3.x and I would like to speed my code by parallelizing my functions using the multiprocessing, I applied the multiprocessing but for some reason, it didn't work probably, I am not sure where is the problem?

so the following is a small example of what I did.
Any suggestions are appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import math
import multiprocessing as mp

lower_bound = -500
upper_bound =500 
dimension =1000
Base_Value = 10
Popula_size = 3000
MinResolution = 8

population_in = np.random.choice ( np.linspace ( lower_bound , upper_bound , Base_Value ** MinResolution ) , size = ( Popula_size , dimension ) , replace = True )
resolution = np.random.randint(1, 8, size = (1, dimension))

def Discretiz(lower_bound, upper_bound, DiscPopulation, resolution):
        
    pop_size = int(len(DiscPopulation))
    the_new_population = np.zeros ((pop_size, dimension))
    for i in range (pop_size) :
        for ii in range (dimension):          
            decimal = int(np.round((DiscPopulation[i][ii] - lower_bound) / ((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1))))
            the_new_population[i, ii]  = (lower_bound + decimal *  ((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1)))
    return the_new_population


# without_parallelizing
# the_new_population = Discretiz(lower_bound, upper_bound, population_in, resolution)


# wit_parallelizing
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
the_new_population = [pool.apply(Discretiz, args=(lower_bound, upper_bound, population_in, resolution))]


print (the_new_population)
```

Comment: Why are you using `math` functions when `numpy` can do the same thing - on a whole array.   `math.power` requires scalar inputs, forcing you to use the slow double `for` loop.  You should maximize your use of `numpy` before jumping on the multiprocessing bandwagon.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your help, but how I can apply numpy power to my work like the math power `math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1)` for example

Comment: Could you also add what didn't work and how did you determine that?

Comment: @atru could you please see my answer

Comment: I gave your code a closer look: you need to specify, for yourself, what are you exactly trying to parallelize and how. It may be as simple as a parallel [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) and a shared array, but I'd need to refresh more for details.

Comment: In your answer the parallelization simply runs the same thing as the serial version + parallelization start/stop overhead which is what your timing is capturing. In your question, from the back of my head, you simply run the same thing at the same time on each core + overhead, which will be slower than serial for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
population_in = np.random.choice ( np.linspace ( lower_bound , upper_bound , Base_Value ** MinResolution ) , size = ( Popula_size , dimension ) , replace = True )
```

you make a 2d array `(Popula_size, dimension)` shape.   This is passed as `DiscPopulation`.

```
resolution = np.random.randint(1, 8, size = (1, dimension))
```

The double iteration function can be replaced with one that operates on whole arrays without the slow iteration:

```
def Discretiz(lower_bound, upper_bound, DiscPopulation, resolution):
    pop_size = DiscPopulation[0]  # no need for the 'int'
    num = DiscPopulation - lower_bound
    divisor = (upper_bound-lower_bound)/(Base_value**resolution-1)
    decimal = num/divisor
    # this divide does (pop,dimension)/(1,dimension); ok by broadcasting)
    decimal = np.round(decimal)  # no need for int
    the_new_population = lower_bound + decimal * divisor
    return the_new_population
```

I wrote this in-place here.  It is syntactically correct, but I have not tried to run it.

Comment: this is the best answer ever for me, do you know from this I change most of my code because most of the `for loops` are deleted. programing is about the way how we think. thank you again I learn a lot from this :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code now but still not faster than the old one it takes more time not sure why?
without parallelizing: 25.831339597702026 seconds
with parallelizing: 44.12706518173218 seconds ???!!!

```
import numpy as np
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Manager, Pool, cpu_count
import time

lower_bound = -500
upper_bound =500 
dimension =1000
Base_Value = 10
Popula_size = 2000
MinResolution = 8

population_in = np.random.choice ( np.linspace ( lower_bound , upper_bound , Base_Value ** MinResolution ) , size = ( Popula_size , dimension ) , replace = True )
resolution = np.random.randint(1, 8, size = (1, dimension))

start_time = time.time()
def Discretiz1(DiscPopulation, resolution):
# def Discretiz1(DiscPopulation):
    DiscPopulation = np.reshape(DiscPopulation, (Popula_size, dimension))
    resolution = np.reshape(resolution, (1,dimension))
    the_new_population = np.zeros ((Popula_size, dimension))
    for i in range (Popula_size) :
        for ii in range (dimension):          
            decimal = int(np.round((DiscPopulation[i][ii] - lower_bound) / ((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1))))
            the_new_population[i, ii]  = (lower_bound + decimal *  ((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1)))
    # print(the_new_population)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_cores = cpu_count()
    Pool(processes=num_cores)
    population_in = np.reshape(population_in, (1,Popula_size * dimension))[0]
    resolution = np.reshape(resolution, (1,dimension))[0]
    arr1 = Array('d', population_in)
    arr2 = Array('i', resolution)
    
    start_time = time.time()
    p = Process(target=Discretiz1, args=(arr1, arr2))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print('--- %s seconds ---'%(time.time() - start_time))
    
print("--- %s seconds ---3" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

this is the olde one or without parallelizing:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Manager, Pool, cpu_count
import time

lower_bound = -500
upper_bound =500 
dimension =1000
Base_Value = 10
Popula_size = 2000
MinResolution = 8

population_in = np.random.choice ( np.linspace ( lower_bound , upper_bound , Base_Value ** MinResolution ) , size = ( Popula_size , dimension ) , replace = True )
resolution = np.random.randint(1, 8, size = (1, dimension))

start_time = time.time()
def Discretiz(lower_bound, upper_bound, DiscPopulation, resolution):
        
    pop_size = int(len(DiscPopulation))
    the_new_population = np.zeros ((pop_size, dimension))
    for i in range (pop_size) :
        for ii in range (dimension):          
            decimal = int(np.round((DiscPopulation[i][ii] - lower_bound) / ((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1))))
            the_new_population[i, ii]  = (lower_bound + decimal *  ((upper_bound-lower_bound)/(math.pow(Base_Value,resolution[:,ii])-1)))
    return the_new_population

# without_parallelizing
the_new_population = Discretiz(lower_bound, upper_bound, population_in, resolution)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```